# Do ASP.Net MVC Portable areas work with Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, portable-areas

I have an Umbraco website that I want to extend. I feel that ASP.Net MVC is the way to go for the extension I'm writing - I particularly like the idea of a Portable Area from MVCContrib. What I'm wondering is, how straightforward would it be to incorporate the Portable Area into Umbraco without recompiling the source?

More generally, is it possible to wire a portable area into an existing application just by modifying web.config? I'm thinking along the lines of creating a HttpModule and including that in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

No, portable areas require a VirtualPathProvider to be set.  VirtualPathProviders must be configured via code.

You could try some hacktastic approach using the App_Code folder.  It may work.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Umbraco (4.x) is based on the web-forms model so it won't be easy incorporating MVC into it (though I believe Umbraco 5 - still in planning - will be MVC based).

Generally you either user XSLT or web-form User Controls to add functionality to an Umbraco site. However, I'm not clear what the "extension" you are writing actually does? Perhaps you could expand upon what it is designed to achieve?

Comment: The functionality is really completely unrelated to the rest of the site: it just want to tag it onto the existing app so that I don't have to pay for a new site at the hosting company! As I understand it, Umbraco has to be at the route of the site, so there's no way for me to add an additional app.

Comment: Perhaps iou could create folder under the root and then get Umbraco to ignore it by editing the umbracoReservedPaths line in web.config Then you could add whatever asp.net code you liked there.

Comment: Dan - didn't know about umbracoReservedPaths - I'll have a look at that. Thanks!